# LEAdvertisingManager1 missing from DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects

Tags: linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, dbus, bluez

I'm running tests with my home computer running Ubuntu and Python 2.7 in the hopes of having Raspberry Pi 3 advertise using BLE with custom services and characteristics. I've installed Bluez Version 5.42 (using the recommended method) on both devices as well as dbus-python. My computer and Raspberry Pi both are able to advertise using the `hci0 lescan 0` command, but I'd like to advertise with the bluez example scripts, example-gatt-client.py and example-advertisement.py found [here](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/bluez/tree/master/test), as I want to use my own custom characteristics.

**Home Computer - Kernel version 4.4.0-31 generic**

I'm able to create custom characteristics and advertise by running example-gatt-server.py and example-advertise.py with no issues on my home computer. The one snag I had was I needed to enable Bluez experimental mode by adding `--experimental` to the bluetooth.service file located in `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`. Also installing the dbus-python library was a bit of a pain, as I had to build and install it myself for Python2.

The advertise.py script looks for a specific advertising interface called "org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1". The gatt-server.py script looks for "org.bluez.GattManager1". I can check if that interface exists by running the following command:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects
```

These interfaces are found and work fine on my home computer. The scripts run without issue.

**Raspberry Pi - Kernel version 4.4.38-v7+**

With the same bluez version and the experimental features enabled, I run into this error when trying to run advertise.py:

> LEAdvertisingManager1 interface not found.

And when I execute the command "systemctl status bluetooth" it shows the experimental flag is enabled, but I don't see LEAdvertistingManager1 when running.

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects
```

I can however run the gatt-server.py script without issue which means "org.bluez.GattManager1" is found and working properly. What am I missing here?

I've searched this issue, but the only suggestions were to enable experimental features and ensure my kernel is >= 4.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've solved my issue! After a lot of debugging and looking through the bluez error logs, I realized that I did not install bluez correctly on my Pi. Here are the steps for properly installing bluez from a fresh install of raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
mkdir bluez 
cd bluez 
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.43.tar.xz 
tar xvf bluez-5.43.tar.xz 
cd bluez-5.43/ 
sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev 
./configure 
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

Then, enable experimental mode. This may not be required with Bluez v5.23 but I did it anyway.

```
cd
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
```

Add --experimental after the line "ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd"
So it should look like

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental
```

Then to get bluetooth running with this new configuration

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

If you want to run a test advertisement you can just use the following:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hcio leadv 0
```

Your Pi3 should advertise as "raspberrypi" and if you try to connect to it using your favorite BLE app (I use LiteBlue on iOS) it should have a few default characteristics.

In order to check if 'LEAdvertisingManager1' exists, we need to run

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects
```

Finally, don't try to run the scripts from the link in my original post. They're so incredibly out of date. Instead, run the example scripts located in the directory you made.

```
cd bluez/bluez-5.43/tests
```

Before running, you'll want to install dbus-python via the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev 
sudo apt-get install python-pip 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gi
sudo python2.7 -m pip install dbus-python
```

If you want to run the example-advertise script using python2.7 (which I did), you'll have to change the line in example-advertise from

```
import gobject
```

to

```
from gi.repository import GObject as gobject
```

If you want to add your own custom characteristics, you'll need to **concurrently** run example-gatt-server which should run without modifications.

I also had a small issue where my iPhone was stuck interrogating the Pi3 and would not connect. This was solved by simply resetting the bluetooth.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. However on a Raspi 3 I get: `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` –> `Can't get device info: No such device`. Should we apply the patch before running `make` as described in https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/issues/30?

Comment: This now works for me: I applied both the hciattach-patch (don't know if't necessary though) and I also run `sudo /usr/bin/hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -`). A reboot might be necessary in between. `sudo hcitool lescan` discovers peripherals.

Comment: Thanks. worked great! I didn't need the manual install of bluez though, just adding --experimental, then daemon-reload and restart bluetooth!

Answer (score 1):

While this is getting Bluetoothctl to latest version of Bluez, Bluetoothd stays at 5.23 which is old version. Problem seems to be that when you install pi-bluetooth it install 5.23 as dependency. How to get Blueoothd also to latest version? I noticed is clearly gets installed from steps above. After reboot still at 5.23.

pi@raspberrypi:~/bluez-5.37 $ bluetoothd -v
5.23
pi@raspberrypi:~/bluez-5.37 $ bluetoothctl -v
5.37

Comment: Did you try the full path? The make file didn't replace the original executable when I ran it, it put it in a different folder. You might try `/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --version`.